# Подписать xml файл цифровой подписью с ключем (key.dat) и паролем C#

Tags: c#, x509certificate

Доброе время суток, у меня задача, подписать file.xml, ключем key-6.dat с паролем 1234.
Пробовал использовать System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.

```
string Filename = "C:/Users/Key-6.dat";
        string Password = "2910";
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(Filename, Password);
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCsp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;
```

получаю ошибку: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The specified network password is not correct.

Comment: И что именно пошло не так? Для чего вам подпись?

Comment: в результате должен получится файл с расширение .p7s который я выгружаю post запросом на сервер

Comment: когда подписываю таким образом, получаю ошибку System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The specified network password is not correct.
'

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос, его можно отредактировать.

Comment: а что такое key-6.dat? вы его случайно не у КНЕДП ІДД ДПС или другого украинского сертификационный центра получали?

Comment: "КНЕДП ІДД ДПС или другого украинского центра получали " - так и есть, у них

Comment: у них какой-то специальный формат, насколько я понял для X509 не подойдет, можно поискать есть реализации для node.js которые его поддерживаю, но про .net я не знаю

Comment: Поделитесь тем что есть, если можно

Comment: https://github.com/dstucrypt/agent и https://github.com/dstucrypt/jkurwa так можно посмотреть примеры, как ими пользоваться, но насколько они рабочие/безопасные, хз

Comment: не пошло, может есть есть что то ..